# Saved Experiment missing after 24h in Azure ML free workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I had created a free Azure machine learning workspace. 
Created an experiment while following a tutorial.
Saved the experiment multiple times through the process.
Next day when i came back to the workspace, i no longer see the saved experiment.

Is this expected? Is it a limitation of a free workspace?
i could not see it mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind this one. I was checking to see if this was the default behavior of free workspace, so i created another experiment and logged off and back in.
Voila, now i see both my experiments!! 
Still there was a sample experiment (not saved by me) missing, that was there earlier.
I dont know what caused this blip, but im okay for now.